# Home page sidebar - "faq" tag popup content is aligned to the right

Tags: bug, design, per-site-meta, popups, sidebar

There is an alignment issue in the "faq" section's tag description, which is in the "Frequently Asked" section of the sidebar of the Home page in the [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and per-site meta sites, such as [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

The tag description is right aligned, whereas in other places the tag description is left aligned.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: "faq" tag description alignment issue - image]

**GIF for reference:**

[image: "faq" tag description alignment issue - gif]

Comment: Maybe they're aligned to the right because the faq tag is also aligned to the right?

Comment: @Joachim yes, the parent container has `ta-right` class attached to it, to make it aligned to the right, and it also affects the child elements in it. If I remove the class, the tag popup is fine.